# Can detect a second or third referral?

Tags: php, http-referer, user-tracking

Hello stackoverflow community

par example, my website is `test-3.com` and someone visit `test-1.com` and from it redirect to `test-2.com` and from it redirect to my website `test-3.com`,

question here: can detect first referral `test-1.com` ? if yes, can detect more than 2 websites visited before come to my website ?

from web programming side as generally is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only track one referer, unless you use some parameters in the url; i.e;
test-1.com > redirect to test-2.com > redirect with param test-3.com?firstref=firstref